# PyGears reordering bits

Tags: pygears

I would like to reorder bits before sending it to another module. I would like to make gear that will take 2 inputs pixel and weight and output called reordered should be:

```
reordered[0] = {pixel[0],weight[0]}
reordered[1] = {pixel[1],weight[1]}
```

Below is a picture that explains desired gear:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made the assumption that both pixels and weights are coming as one interface thus I group it. This module should look something like this:

```
@datagear 
def reorder( din: Queue[Tuple['pixel', 'weight']] ) -> Array[Queue[Tuple['pixel.data', 'weight.data']], 3]: 
    pixel  = din.data[0] 
    weight = din.data[1] 

    return ( 
        ((pixel[0], weight[0]), din.eot), 
        ((pixel[1], weight[1]), din.eot), 
        ((pixel[2], weight[2]), din.eot), 
    )
```

Datagear is generally used for handling data and reordering it.

**But please have in mind that if Pixel and Weight were two interfaces additional logic would be generated for synchronization of these two interfaces.**